# Android : how to get result back from service in the launching activity

Tags: android, service

Here is my problem :

I have an activity were the user enter the data of a "problem"
 - This activity launch a service (by intention) with the data of the problem
 - The service compute the solution of the problem
 - And I want to send this solution to the activity so it can print if on the screen.

The problem is that I don't want to start the activity again ... do you have an idea of how i can do that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

What happens if the user presses BACK or HOME after entering in the "data of a 'problem'", before the "solution" is ready?

If the answer is that you do not need to do anything, then get rid of the `Service`, and have the `Activity` do the work to compute the solution (perhaps using an `AsyncTask`). You are not gaining anything in this case by using a `Service`.

If, however, the user will still want the "solution", then using a `Service` is fine, but you have to take into account that the `Activity` that started the service may no longer exist or may not be in the foreground.

One way to handle this is to use an ordered broadcast. Have the `Activity` register a high-priority `BroadcastReceiver` for the broadcast when it is in the foreground (via `onResume()` and `onPause()`), and register a low-priority `BroadcastReceiver` for the same broadcast via the manifest. The `Service` would `sendOrderedBroadcast()` when its work is complete. The `Activity`-registered `BroadcastReceiver` would update its UI with the result and abort the broadcast. The manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver` would raise a `Notification` to let the user know about the completed work. [Here is a blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/08/11/activity-notification-ordered-broadcast.html) with more about this pattern, and [here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Broadcast/Ordered) that demonstrates its use.