# services and onactivityresult

Tags: android, service

I want to do speech recognition which runs in background and receive its contents and then perform an action. All this should be done in background.

I have done the recognition thing, just want it to run in background.

Is there any way??? please help !!!!

It is same as 
[Handle onActivityResult on a Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13608236/handle-onactivityresult-on-a-service)

But I did not understood the answer 
Can you please explain ?

Comment: I have not tried anything. I am not able to understand how could i run speech recognition in background. I thought It could be done by using services but its not. onactivityresult is not supported in services. is there any other way ???

Comment: can anyone explain answer given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13608236/handle-onactivityresult-on-a-service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In My opinion Service doesn't send result. But I knew some links that can be useful to you
[how does a service return result to an activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841043/how-does-a-service-return-result-to-an-activity)
[Android : how to get result back from service in the launching activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547263/android-how-to-get-result-back-from-service-in-the-launching-activity)
[start a remote service and receive a result in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10142249/start-a-remote-service-and-receive-a-result-in-android)

Hope they are helpful